# PayPal form submissions shows 404 PayPal page when link is clicked from Facebook messenger in iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, facebook, paypal, facebook-messenger

Following is the PayPal form and form submission script. It works well in Android and Desktop but when link is opened from Facebook messenger in iPhone, it shows PayPal 404 not found page.

Reference code is as below:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_form_url; ?>" method="post" id="pyPal">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_email; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo strtoupper( str_replace("_", " ", $record_find_slug['NewCheckout']['name']) ) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="NA">
        <input type="hidden" id="paypal_amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo $payment_data['CheckoutUser']['amount'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" id="paypal_invoice_id" name="invoice" value="<?php echo base64_decode($invoice_id); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="paypal_return" name="return" value="<?php echo $return_url; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/checks/paypal_payment">
        <input style="display: none;" id="paypal_submit_trigger" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/PP_logo_h_150x38.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#pyPal").submit(); }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: What HTML does this render to when fetched from a browser?

Comment: @PrestonPHX HTML 5

Comment: The contents of the page

Comment: @PrestonPHX Please review - https://prnt.sc/gvotALGkcHJx

Comment: @PrestonPHX after 3 seconds page redirects to PayPal 404 not found page. this happens only when link shared in Facebook Messenger on IPhone, in other cases works fine.

Comment: The contents in text format so they can be tested and analyzed, not a screenshot of code

Comment: @PrestonPHX can you please copy the PayPal form from above and place it in a web page and try to open the link from FB Messenger.

Comment: @PrestonPHX By doing so on FB Messenger on Iphone, PayPal 404 not found page is shown. However works fine in other devices.

Comment: No I cannot, because it is PHP rather than the resulting HTML